# rolling dice simulation with three different dice

Tags: python

I have created a program that lets the use enter what dice they want and it work but I don't no how to get it so it will ask again

```
import random
while True:
    rollagain="yes"
    print("your dices available to you are a 4 sided dice a 6 sided dice and a 12 sided dice")
    dice=input("which sided dice would you like to roll")
    if dice =="4":
        dicenumber=random.randint(1,4)
        print("dice rolled ",dice,"and number rolled is",dicenumber,)
    elif dice =="6":
        dicenumber=random.randint(1,6)
        print("dice rolled ",dice,"and number rolled is",dicenumber,)
    elif dice =="12":
        dicenumber=random.randint(1,12)
        print("dice rolled ",dice,"and number rolled is",dicenumber,)
    elif dice != "4" or dice != "6" or dice != "12":
        print ("this dice is not available please choose one available")
        rollagain=input("would you like to roll again? if you do enter yes, if not enter no.")
        print("thank you for playing")
        break
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"? Is there an error? Does it not output what you expect?

Comment: your dices avalibe to you are a 4 sided dice a 6 sided dice and a 12 sided dice
which sided dice would you like to roll4
dice rolled  4 and number rolled is 3
would you like to roll again? if you do enter yes, if not enter no.yes
your dices avalibe to you are a 4 sided dice a 6 sided dice and a 12 sided dice
which sided dice would you like to roll8
this dice is not avalible please choose one avalible, enter 4, 6 or 12
would you like to roll again? if you do enter yes, if not enter no.

Comment: that's what I output so it works but if I type 8 in its meant to output  this dice is not avalible please choose one avalible, enter 4, 6 or 12 would you like to roll again? but notwould you like to roll again? if you do enter yes, if not enter no. is there any code to stop this happening

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_choice(prompt,choices):
    val = raw_input(prompt):
    if val not in choices:
       print "Invalid Solution! Please Enter %s or %s"%(", ".join(choices[:-1]),choices[-1])
       return get_choice(prompt,choices)
    return val

print "You entered :",get_choice("Select Dice Type:","4 6 8 12".split())
```

as long as they get it right before 1000 times wrong this should work